# After hiding dropdown list, show it again on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fix an issue with a dropdown-list. I want to hide the dropdown-list on mouseleave, but when I click the button again to show the dropdown-list, it's still hidden.

```js
$('ul.dropdown-menu').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
 
});

$('.icm-link').on('click', function(event) {
  idP = $(this).val();
  shellID = $(this).attr('data-value');

  $('#' + idP).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-value='shellId' type="button" style='color: #2f84ff;height: 30px !important;width: 40px !important;' value='rowId' class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle icm-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt'  style='color: #2f84ff;' aria-hidden='true'></span>
</button>
<ul id='links' class="dropdown-menu links" style="position: absolute;">
  <li><a id='so' onclick='shellOverview()' href="#">Shell Overview</a></li>
  <li><a id='op' onclick='onePager()' href="#">One Pager</a></li>
  <li><a id='ds' onclick='decisionSheet()' href="#">Decision Sheet</a></li>
  <li><a id='sd' onclick='shellDecision()' href="#">Shell Decision</a></li>
  <li><a id='pm' onclick='partModel()' href="#">Partmodel</a></li>
  <li><a id='mt' onclick='milestoneTracking()' href="#">Milestone Tracking</a></li>
  <li><a id='ev' onclick='engineeringView()' href="#">Engineering View</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please show relevant html

Comment: The `toggle()` call is redundant and can be removed. That's not going to affect the issue you have though, so we need to see the code as @MaheerAli pointed out.

Comment: I put it in above :)

Comment: Why do you have toggle() than show() ???

Comment: @epascarello sorry, my fault.. removed it :-D

Comment: have you looked your PHP echos?
I've made the same code as you, but with fixes IDs and woked fine.

Comment: There's no `fixColumns()` function in the code you've shared, so the snippet won't work...

Comment: The code does not work with the code because the show code never works to start. value="rowId" and there is no id="rowId"

Comment: The unedited code had a dinamic id, id="<?=array['id'] ?>"

Comment: I think that the button's attrib value has to be 'links' instead 'rowid'

Comment: So the button is in my table in a <td> tag. every td has an ID which opens a link for the curtain ID. Because of that I need a dynamic ID for my button.

Comment: Sorry, meant every <tr> has an ID..

Answer (score 2):

The $('.icm-link') is a button:

```
$('.icm-link').on('click', function(event) {
  idP = $(this).val();
```

Change .val to .attr('value')

```
$('.icm-link').on('click', function(event) {
  idP = $(this).attr('value');
```

```js
$('ul.dropdown-menu').on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  $(this).hide();
});

$('.icm-link').on('click', function(event) {
  idP = $(this).attr('value'); 
  shellID = $(this).attr('data-value'); 

  $('#' + idP).toggle();
  $('#' + idP).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button data-value='1' type="button" style='color: #2f84ff;height: 30px !important;width: 40px !important;' value='1' class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle icm-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt'  style='color: #2f84ff;' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul id='1' class="dropdown-menu links" style="position: absolute;">
                            <li><a id='so' onclick='shellOverview()' href="#">Shell Overview</a></li>
                            <li><a id='op' onclick='onePager()' href="#">One Pager</a></li>
                            <li><a id='ds' onclick='decisionSheet()' href="#">Decision Sheet</a></li>
                            <li><a id='sd' onclick='shellDecision()' href="#">Shell Decision</a></li>
                            <li><a id='pm' onclick='partModel()' href="#">Partmodel</a></li>
                            <li><a id='mt' onclick='milestoneTracking()' href="#">Milestone Tracking</a></li>
                            <li><a id='ev' onclick='engineeringView()' href="#">Engineering View</a></li>
                          </ul>
```

Comment: `val()` works on buttons... is there a specific reason you need to use `attr('value')` here?

Comment: Yeah, it worked with .val() too.
Must be something with the php ids that he is including.